# PHP class: force a certain file extension

Tags: php, class, docx

I come to ask for your help because I can't find a solution.

In short, I would like to restrict a variable (which is the path + name of a file) to a certain type of file extension in the construct of one of my classes.

I know I can check the extension with the pathinfo function, but i don't know how to fit it to the construct of a class.

So I would like that, if the file doesn't exist or the extension is different from .docx, the construct returns an error and prevents calling the functions of the object

Thanks a lot for your help !

PS : I'm pretty new to PHP and I apologize in advance for my English translator ><

EDIT : Some code

```
class abc {
public string $path;

public function __construct($path) {
    $this->path = $path;

    if(pathinfo($this->path)['extension'] !== 'docx' && !file_exists($this->path)) {
        //throws an error and prevents the function call
    }
}
```

Comment: Share some code,

Comment: Its update, but I don't see how it will help

Comment: To throw errors in OOP matter you [throw](https://php.net/throw) an exception. But doing so in the constructor means that `new abc()` can throw exceptions, which can be a bit unexpected.